# Functional programming method, or most Pythonic way, to loop over an array using two adjacent variables at a time

Tags: python, arrays, functional-programming, language-agnostic

Consider the problem: Given an array of integers, returning the number of times at which the array is decreasing. So [3,2,1] is decreasing twice (at 3 and 2); [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] is decreasing 4 times (at 5, 4, 3, 2), and [1] is decreasing none.

It's extremely easy to solve this in a for loop in any language:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i+1]) result += 1;
}
```

I only know how to solve this using a for or while loop and keeping track of the index. I don't know any functional way using a method like `map` or using lists or comprehensions but that's what I would like to hope exists.

Comment: "without using a for or while loop, or keeping track of the index, or using functional toolbox methods like map or filters or comprehensions." - I don't know what you're looking for. There's nothing else left.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sorry, my grammar was ambiguous. It's clarified.

Comment: I'm looking how to do this too. Making a recursive function works, but now, how do you emulate "continue" and "break" when iterating though loops in functional programming?

Answer (score 6):

One nice way of doing this is using the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) method in combination with [sum](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
sum(a > b for a, b in zip(array, array[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if python arrays have a reduce function, but if they have, you could do something that in javascript would be done this way:

```
let result = 0;
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1].reduce((prev,current) => {
    if (prev > current){
        result = result + 1;;
    }
    return current;
});

console.log(result); // 4 for the given array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a recursive function.

```
def decreasing(xs):
    if len(xs) < 2:
        return 0
    (x0, x1, *xss) = xs
    if x0 > x1:
        return 1 + decreasing([x1] + xss)
    return decreasing([x1] + xss)
```

I'm not sure creating multiple lists like this in python is healthy though.